# WPF: Convert string to System.Windows.Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

Currently I am working with databases and I'm standing in front a little problem. I have an app and in this app each user can set certain parts of the app that are not needed to "invisible" so that they are not shown anymore. 
I save this information for each user in a database, so that the app can directly adopt any changes or settings set by the user the previous time he used it. In that database the visibility-property is saved as a string.
For example I have the following variable saved in my database:

```
string str = Convert.ToString(System.Windows.Visibility.Visible);
```

and now I start my app again and read that variable, which should represent the visibility property of a Grid named "grid" and to set this property what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
grid.Visibility = reader.GetString(1);
}
```

Unfortunately with this I get the Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to System.Windows.Visibility
Does anyone have an idea for an alternative solution or a possibility to Convert a string to a visibility?

Hopefully it is clear what I'd like to do and thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Instead of storing a string you could simply store a boolean value, and restore it by `grid.Visibility = visible ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.Windows.Visibility` is an Enum, and Enum has `Parse` method to obtain value from string. Parse returns `object` value, an explicit cast required:

```
grid.Visibility = (System.Windows.Visibility)
 Enum.Parse(typeof(System.Windows.Visibility), reader.GetString(1));
```

Comment: That looks like what I need, do I put that code in one line?

Comment: @MaChaToc, it is up to you :) If I make it one-line in the answer, a horizontal scroll appears - and I don't like h.scroll because it hides part of the code - it was the only reason for linebreak here

Comment: Got it, I'll try it and let you know if it worked :)

Comment: Note that you would also have to catch the ArgumentException that is thrown when the string is not a valid name of one of the enum constants. You should really not store a string.

Comment: @Clemens you are right and I considered that, too. But to me that seemed as the most straightforward way to do it.

Comment: @MaChaToc, nice! Enum also has `TryParse` method with `out` parameter which return true or false - success of parsing. It does the same for correct string values, but doesn't throw Exception on incorrect (returns false)

Comment: @ASh So this way the exception handling is also covered, right?

Comment: @MaChaToc, TryParse doesn't throw exception, there is nothing to handle. but invalid input is covered, yes

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way is `grid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

Why you just don't use a condition?

```
if(reader.GetString(1).Equals("Visible")) {
   grid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
} else {
   grid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: Your way is better yes, but well it's just an other else if for hidden if he wants to, still working